# What's the one word for "Take the Lead"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

what can I use as a synonym for "take the lead" preferably in one word?

Comment: Diala, Could you explain why you need this alternative to what is a perfectly good expression?  As you know, one thing ELU asks for  is that the asker gives context and reason for the request.

Comment: Is it a race?   A project? What?

Comment: You can get it down to two words:  "get shot".

Comment: *I **took the lead from** her.* → *I* [**overtook**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overtake) *her.*

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward is simply "lead": "you lead, I'll follow" is equivalent to "you take the lead, I'll follow". It works for "lead" in the sense of tasks or actual paths.

There are plenty of synonymous phrases but all the single word synonyms (I can think of) only work in some situations, and have other connotations anyway ("guide", "direct").

Comment: Hmm I'd said that too, but there's a subtle difference in that the *take* is not there for nothing, right?

Comment: @Kris maybe, but I can't define any reason for *take* in the general case (a suggestion of assuming leadership from someone else might need it).  English,  especially business English, seems rather prone to adding superfluous words: many uses of "in order to" could simply be served by "to" etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think "spearhead" is a good option.

> serve as leader or leading element of

Source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spearhead#synonyms)